# Python Chess Validation move

Tags: python

I am new to programming and I am trying to implement a small chess game.

I am currently struggling with the validations move for each piece.

Each piece is an object inheriting from a higher class "ChessPiece".
The board is a `dict` of 64 elements ('board array'): top left is element 0 (i.e. A8 is the black rook on the black sloth) while the bottom right element 64 is (i.e. H1 is the white rook on the black sloth).

The user inputs the coordinate, example a1, and through a dictionary the program retrive the index in the 'board array'.

The dictionary is:

```
board_array= {
    "a8": 0, "a7": 8, "a6": 16, "a5": 24, "a4": 32, "a3": 40, "a2": 48, "a1": 56,
    "b8": 1, "b7": 9, "b6": 17, "b5": 25, "b4": 33, "b3": 41, "b2": 49, "b1": 57,
    "c8": 2, "c7": 10, "c6": 18, "c5": 26, "c4": 34, "c3": 42, "c2": 50, "c1": 58,
    "d8": 3, "d7": 11, "d6": 19, "d5": 27, "d4": 35, "d3": 43, "d2": 51, "d1": 59,
    "e8": 4, "e7": 12, "e6": 20, "e5": 28, "e4": 36, "e3": 44, "e2": 52, "e1": 60,
    "f8": 5, "f7": 13, "f6": 21, "f5": 29, "f4": 37, "f3": 45, "f2": 53, "f1": 61,
    "g8": 6, "g7": 14, "g6": 22, "g5": 30, "g4": 38, "g3": 46, "g2": 54, "g1": 62,
    "h8": 7, "h7": 15, "h6": 23, "h5": 31, "h4": 39, "h3": 47, "h2": 55, "h1": 63,
}
```

I have created a function in each subclass (Pawn, Rook, Queen...) that should validate the move.
The syntax is something like:

```
def isvalid(self, final_position):
   #Check if the final_position is valid. If it is valid, return True and thus the program che update the instance position. Otherwise, return False and re-ask the user to input a valid final_position
```

Currently I can move any white piece in any white sloth or sloth with a black piece on it (but I cannot eat myself) and vice versa.

The issue is that I do not know how to start to validate.

I guess the fact that I am using a `dict` for the board and not a list of lists makes thing harder. 
I am really lost. It would be amazing if you could help me by showing a validation, maybe for an easier piece such as the Rook.

Comment: I'm not sure if that board array is the most useful way to represent the coordinates, given you're having trouble understanding it for validate. Could you pick something else? For the rook the 'a8' form might be easier if you still have that - it's a valid move if the target square is either a-something or something-8. Although in your digit form that corresponds to either square/8 (integer division) staying the same or square%8 staying the same.

Comment: For starts, you're not using a `list`. You're using a `dict`. I would definitely recommend using a list of lists.

Comment: Yes, I can retrieve any position "letter_number" to "integer" and vice versa. Example: if I have a8 I know it is 0 , and if I have 0 I know it is a8.

Comment: Or if you used a list and in the 0th position you put a8 you could do the same thing you are currently doing and lose the problems of doing this with a dictionary

Answer (score 0):

For rook:

```
 def invalid(pos, target):

       d0 = 1 if pos[0]>target[0] else -1
       d1 = 1 if pos[1]>target[1] else -1
       return any(board_array[i + j ] for i, j in zip(range(target[0], pos[0], d0 ), range(target[1], pos[1], d1 ))]
```

Comment: Is 'pos' the current_position and 'target' the final position?

Comment: yup, sorry written from a cell